# Can you get IP adress for all devices in your network when connected to wifi Windows phone 8

Tags: sockets, networking, windows-phone-8, ip

So the question is, when using sockets and using DnsEndPoint you have to provied hostIp... Is there a way to find out all devices that use same wi-fi as your phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to do that. To get all devices and their details, .NET Framework utilizes System.DirectoryService Namespace. This namespace is not available in Windows Phone.

Comment: hm, can you then achieve this from desktop? scan for ips, to get ip of windows phone to computer, and then still establish connection where computer is server and phone is client?

Comment: There is no way for that. Windows Phone registry cannot be accessed to retrieve OS version information.